# How are you able to know when a file is downloaded into a specific file in c#?

Tags: c#

I am writing a program that requires that a folder such as the downloads folder is monitored and whenever a file or a folder is downloaded a certain condition is tripped. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: "this question does not show any research effort"

Comment: @roryap[link](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+are+you+able+to+know+when+a+file+is+downloaded+into+a+specific+file+in+c%23%3F&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS656US656&oq=How+are+you+able+to+know+when+a+file+is+downloaded+into+a+specific+file+in+c%23%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57.640j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @MiekShreds -- what is that comment for?  Your question needs to demonstrate that you did research before you posted it.  That's one of the main reasons you get down votes.  Don't put a link to me in your comments; *edit your question instead*.

Comment: @roryap Because I have looked? there aren't any questions asked about this specific need. Chill

Comment: @MiekShreds -- if you hover your mouse cursor over the "vote down" button, the tool tip that pops up is "this question does not show any research effort" .   I didn't make it up.

Comment: @MiekShreds -- I think you need to take a good look at this before posting any more questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just because you did a quick Google search doesn't mean you've shown the effort in the question. Also, on that link you posted in your comment to @roryap, 4th result down... Did you even look that far?

Comment: Every other search result contains what you need to download not for watching for a file to be downloaded. I.E. "Download file and automatically save to folder"

Comment: @MiekShreds -- Then *say that* in your question.  That's the point. does not *show* any research effort.  We don't know what research you did if you didn't include it.  Hence down votes.

Comment: @MiekShreds -- Like I said, you should read over that "how to ask" and other material in the help section.

Comment: @roryap Why would it matter if I put it in or not? I still need the help. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @MiekShreds -- Because that's how it works.  Your question is not just for you.  Once you post it, it belongs to the community.  Others can even edit your question if they want afterwards.

Comment: Additionally, a more well-rounded question that 1.) lists clearly what you're trying to do, 2.) demonstrates what you've tried and explains why it's not working, and 3.) provides evidence and links to research you've done in an effort to resolve it before you posted it will give you a better chance of getting the *specific* help you're looking for.  The community will get a better picture of *precisely* what you're trying to figure out.

Comment: On the other hand, if you don't do all that, your question will get down-votes and will most-likely be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `FileSystemWatcher` you can monitor for the creation and modification of files. However, depending on the application that is writing the file, you can't know when it's *done*. If the application downloads the file directly into the target directory, you will get a notification from the filesystem watcher when the download starts. At that point the file is 0 byte, and will continue growing (potentially giving you more notifications on the watcher).

If you are lucky, the application downloads the file into a separate directory and then *moves* the completed file into the download directory. In that case you will get a single notification when the file is moved into the download dir.

Comment: As long as it  reads that a file is placed in the file that should work